# Check if element exists before trying to call getContext

Tags: javascript, chart.js

This JS contains 3 line charts (Line Chart, Line Chart with Dots, Line Chart Unfilled). How do I check if a chart exists before trying to call getContext for one of the charts?

I found this the below snippet to use to check if the element exists but I'm new and unsure how to replace the function name in the script properly.

```js
<script>
if ( typeof function_name == 'function' ) { 
        //function_name is a function
}
else
{
 //do not exist
}
</script>
```

```js
//------------- Line chart -------------//
 var lineData = {
  labels : ["January","February","March","April","May","June","July"],
  datasets : [
   {
    label: "PayPal",
    fillColor : "rgba(186,195,210,0.2)",
    strokeColor : "rgba(186,195,210,1)",
    pointColor : "rgba(186,195,210,1)",
    pointStrokeColor : "#fff",
    pointHighlightFill : "#fff",
    pointHighlightStroke : "rgba(186,195,210,1)",
    data : [3+randNum(),5+randNum(),8+randNum(),13+randNum(),17+randNum(),21+randNum(),23+randNum()]
   },
   {
    label: "Credit card",
    fillColor : "rgba(96,177,204,0.2)",
    strokeColor : "rgba(96,177,204,1)",
    pointColor : "rgba(96,177,204,1)",
    pointStrokeColor : "#fff",
    pointHighlightFill : "#fff",
    pointHighlightStroke : "rgba(96,177,204,1)",
    data : [randNum()-5,randNum()-2,randNum()-4,randNum()-1,randNum()-3,randNum()-2,randNum()-5]
   }
  ]

 }
 var ctx = document.getElementById("line-chartjs").getContext("2d");
 var myLineChart = new Chart(ctx).Line(lineData, {
  responsive: true,
  scaleShowGridLines : true,
     scaleGridLineColor : "#bfbfbf",
     scaleGridLineWidth : 0.2,
     bezierCurve : false,
     //points
     pointDot : false,
     datasetStroke : true,
     datasetStrokeWidth : 2,
     datasetFill : true,
     //animations
     animation: true,
     animationSteps: 60,
     animationEasing: "easeOutQuart",
     //scale
     showScale: true,
     scaleFontFamily: "'Roboto'",
     scaleFontSize: 13,
     scaleFontStyle: "normal",
     scaleFontColor: "#333",
     //tooltips
     showTooltips: true,
     tooltipFillColor: "#344154",
     tooltipFontFamily: "'Roboto'",
     tooltipFontSize: 13,
     tooltipFontColor: "#fff",
     tooltipYPadding: 8,
     tooltipXPadding: 10,
     tooltipCornerRadius: 2,
     tooltipTitleFontFamily: "'Roboto'",
 });

 //------------- Line chart with dots -------------//
 var lineDotsData = {
  labels : ["Jan","Feb","Mar","Apr","May","Jun","Jul","Aug","Sep","Oct","Nov","Dec"],
  datasets : [
   {
    label: "Suites",
    fillColor : "RGBA(198, 215, 233, .8)",
    strokeColor : "RGBA(198, 215, 233, 1)",
    pointColor : "RGBA(198, 215, 233, 1)",
    pointStrokeColor : "#fff",
    pointHighlightFill : "#fff",
    pointHighlightStroke : "RGBA(198, 215, 233, 1)",
    data : [50220,48719,55398,64298,127198,125102,173261,153901,74698,51598,44320,48720]
   },
            {
    label: "Multi Family",
    fillColor : "RGBA(105, 162, 219, .8)",
    strokeColor : "RGBA(105, 162, 219, 1)",
    pointColor : "RGBA(105, 162, 219, 1)",
    pointStrokeColor : "#fff",
    pointHighlightFill : "#fff",
    pointHighlightStroke : "RGBA(105, 162, 219, 1)",
    data : [49796,48296,54827,63627,126127,124131,171690,151530,74127,51127,43896,48296]
   },
            {
    label: "Bulk",
    fillColor : "RGBA(251, 203, 164, .8)",
    strokeColor : "RGBA(251, 203, 164, 1)",
    pointColor : "RGBA(251, 203, 164, 1)",
    pointStrokeColor : "#fff",
    pointHighlightFill : "#fff",
    pointHighlightStroke : "RGBA(251, 203, 164, 1)",
    data : [47127,45627,51627,59627,121127,119631,162190,139627,70627,47627,41227,45627]
   },
            {
    label: "Commercial",
    fillColor : "RGBA(233, 128, 35, .8)",
    strokeColor : "RGBA(233, 128, 35, 1)",
    pointColor : "RGBA(233, 128, 35, 1)",
    pointStrokeColor : "#fff",
    pointHighlightFill : "#fff",
    pointHighlightStroke : "RGBA(233, 128, 35, 1)",
    data : [43501,42001,48001,56001,117501,116005,158564,136001,67001,44001,37601,42001]
   },
            {
    label: "Single Family",
    fillColor : "RGBA(72, 117, 161, .8)",
    strokeColor : "RGBA(72, 117, 161, 1)",
    pointColor : "RGBA(72, 117, 161, 1)",
    pointStrokeColor : "#fff",
    pointHighlightFill : "#fff",
    pointHighlightStroke : "RGBA(72, 117, 161, 1))",
    data : [38001,36501,42501,48501,105501,101501,142064,121501,59501,38501,32101,36501]
   },
            {
    label: "Non-Revenue Water",
    fillColor : "RGBA(181, 181, 181, .8)",
    strokeColor : "RGBA(181, 181, 181, 1",
    pointColor : "RGBA(181, 181, 181, 1)",
    pointStrokeColor : "#fff",
    pointHighlightFill : "#fff",
    pointHighlightStroke : "RGBA(181, 181, 181, 1)",
    data : [24501,24501,24501,24501,24501,24501,24501,24501,24501,24501,24501,24501]
   },
            {
    label: "System Total",
    fillColor : "RGBA(68, 76, 88, 0)",
    strokeColor : "RGBA(68, 76, 88, 1)",
    pointColor : "RGBA(68, 76, 88, 1)",
    pointStrokeColor : "#fff",
    pointHighlightFill : "#fff",
    pointHighlightStroke : "RGBA(68, 76, 88, 1)",    
    data : [49123,45595,51550,62804,133871,126178,178002,161593,80090,53421,34521,40582]
   }
  ]

 }
 var ctxDots = document.getElementById("line-dots-chartjs").getContext("2d");
 var myLineDotsChart = new Chart(ctxDots).Line(lineDotsData, {
  responsive: true,
  scaleShowGridLines : true,
     scaleGridLineColor : "#bfbfbf",
     scaleGridLineWidth : 0.2,
     bezierCurve : false,
     bezierCurveTension : 0.4,
     //points
     pointDot : true,
     pointDotRadius : 2,
     pointDotStrokeWidth : 1,
     pointHitDetectionRadius : 20,
     datasetStroke : true,
     datasetStrokeWidth : 2,
     datasetFill : true,
     //animations
     animation: true,
     animationSteps: 60,
     animationEasing: "easeOutQuart",
     //scale
     showScale: true,
     scaleFontFamily: "'Roboto'",
     scaleFontSize: 13,
     scaleFontStyle: "normal",
     scaleFontColor: "#333",
     //tooltips
     showTooltips: true,
     tooltipFillColor: "#344154",
     tooltipFontFamily: "'Roboto'",
     tooltipFontSize: 13,
     tooltipFontColor: "#fff",
     tooltipYPadding: 8,
     tooltipXPadding: 10,
     tooltipCornerRadius: 2,
     tooltipTitleFontFamily: "'Roboto'",
 });

 //------------- Line chart unfilled -------------//
 var lineData1 = {
  labels : ["January","February","March","April","May","June","July"],
  datasets : [
   {
    label: "PayPal",
    fillColor : "rgba(186,195,210,0.2)",
    strokeColor : "rgba(186,195,210,1)",
    pointColor : "rgba(186,195,210,1)",
    pointStrokeColor : "#fff",
    pointHighlightFill : "#a1a1a1",
    pointHighlightStroke : "#fff",
    data : [3+randNum(),5+randNum(),8+randNum(),13+randNum(),17+randNum(),21+randNum(),23+randNum()]
   },
   {
    label: "Credit card",
    fillColor : "rgba(67,174,168,0.2)",
    strokeColor : "rgba(67,174,168,1)",
    pointColor : "rgba(67,174,168,1)",
    pointStrokeColor : "#fff",
    pointHighlightFill : "#fff",
    pointHighlightStroke : "rgba(67,174,168,1)",
    data : [randNum()-5,randNum()-2,randNum()-4,randNum()-1,randNum()-3,randNum()-2,randNum()-5]
   }
  ]

 }
 var ctx1 = document.getElementById("line-unfilled-chartjs").getContext("2d");
 var myLineChart1 = new Chart(ctx1).Line(lineData1, {
  responsive: true,
  scaleShowGridLines : true,
     scaleGridLineColor : "#bfbfbf",
     scaleGridLineWidth : 0.2,
     bezierCurve : true,
     //points
     pointDot : false,
     datasetFill : false,
     //animations
     animation: true,
     animationSteps: 60,
     animationEasing: "easeOutQuart",
     //scale
     showScale: true,
     scaleFontFamily: "'Roboto'",
     scaleFontSize: 13,
     scaleFontStyle: "normal",
     scaleFontColor: "#333",
     //tooltips
     showTooltips: true,
     tooltipFillColor: "#344154",
     tooltipFontFamily: "'Roboto'",
     tooltipFontSize: 13,
     tooltipFontColor: "#fff",
     tooltipYPadding: 8,
     tooltipXPadding: 10,
     tooltipCornerRadius: 2,
     tooltipTitleFontFamily: "'Roboto'",
 });
```

Comment: See this to get better answers: http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: @ekuusela thanks. I probably violated every recommendation in that list, my bad. Working on it!

Answer (score 0):

See [Document.getElementById()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementById). That returns `null` if an element with the specified ID is not found. You could do something like this:

```
var chart = document.getElementById("line-unfilled-chartjs");
var ctx;
if (chart) {
    ctx = chart.getContext("2d");
    // do something with context
} else {
    // handle no chart
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use one of this two variant, javascript or jquery

```
// javascript 
var elem = document.getElementById('line-unfilled-chartjs'),
    ctx1;
if (elem !== null){
   // element exist
   ctx1 = elem.getContext("2d");
}

// with jquery
elem = $("#line-unfilled-chartjs");
if (elem.length !== 0)
{
    // element exist
    ctx1 = elem.getContext("2d");
}
```